# JS Array - Check for object value duplicate

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have an array that throws in all data from spreadsheet into studentCCAList.
However, there are instances where a student has multiple subjects.

Here's an example of the log,

Name: **Joseph**

Subject: English

Name: Peter

Math

Name: **Joseph**

Subject: Science

In this case, how do i make sure Joseph is not inserted into 2 array?
The correct one should be

Name: Joseph

Subject: English, Science

```
var studentDataList = [];
var studentCount = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < sheetData.length; ++i) {
    var row = sheetData[i];
    var studentName = row[0];
    var studentSubject = row[1];

    studentDataList[studentCount] = {};
    studentDataList[studentCount].subject = studentSubject;
    studentDataList[studentCount].name = studentName;
    studentCount++;

  }
```

Comment: If the name is unique you can use them as keys in an object with arrays as the values. You can then check if the key is there and if it isn't create it and add the subject to the array, otherwise add the additional subject to the array.

Comment: You can make use of $.inArray (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) function of jQuery to make sure that the name is already in the array or not before populating the array.

Comment: student.name seems almost certain to not be unique over time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with the help of one more array. The code below could help you...

```
var studentDataList = [];
var studentTrack = []; //array which prevents the duplicate values

for (var i = 0; i < sheetData.length; ++i) {
    var row = sheetData[i];
    var studentName = row[0];
    var studentSubject = row[1];

    var index = studentTrack.indexOf(studentName);

    if(index == -1){
      studentDataList.push({
        name: studentName,
        subject: studentSubject
      });

      studentTrack.push(studentName);
    }else{
      studentDataList[index].subject += ", "+studentSubject;
    }

}
```

Comment: Be aware that `Array.prototype.indexOf()` is not supported by <=IE8

Answer (score 2):

This code will do the job in more efficient way

```
var studentDataList = [];
var sheetData = [['Foo','math'],['Foo','science'],['Foo1','math']];
var pushData = function(obj, arr){
    for(var i =0; i<arr.length; i++ ){
        if(arr[i].name === obj.name){
           arr[i].subject+= ', '+obj.subject;
           return;
        }
    }
    arr.push(obj);
}
for (var i = 0; i < sheetData.length; i++) {
    var row = sheetData[i];
    pushData({
        name: row[0],
        subject: row[1]
      },studentDataList);
}
```